# Javascript edit input value by addition

Tags: javascript, function, onchange, addition

So I have this checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="extra-bathroom" name="extra-bathroom" value= "1" style="display: inline;" onchange="updatePrice();">Extra bathroom?
```

Which calls my function fine. I am just working out how to update the value of the below input by addition (I know I can just change the value, but I want to do it by addition)

```
<input id="total-price" type="button" value= 0 style="width: 100%; margin-top: 5px;">
```

**Current JS:**

```
window.updatePrice = function () {

    if (document.getElementById('extra-bathroom').checked) {

        document.getElementById("total-price").value //ADD 42 to value of total-price ;

    }
};
```

Whats my best way of doing this? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="extra-bathroom" name="extra-bathroom" value= "1" style="display: inline;" onchange="updatePrice();">Extra bathroom?
<input id="total-price" type="button" value= 0 style="width: 100%; margin-top: 5px;">
```

Javascript:

```
window.updatePrice = function () {
    if (document.getElementById('extra-bathroom').checked) {
        document.getElementById('total-price').setAttribute("value", parseInt(document.getElementById("total-price").value) + 42);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('total-price').setAttribute("value", parseInt(document.getElementById("total-price").value) - 42);
    }
};
```

Basically, you just get the value (thing you did) and set the attribute "value" of that div to the current value (parsed as an int, else it would concatenate 0 and 42, giving you as a result "042") + 42.

I've also added the case where the checkbox is unchecked. If it is unchecked, it will remove 42 to the current value.

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/s95hvsp5/1/

Comment: That works great thanks. Only thing is it seems to round the numbers. So if my original value is 0.5 instead of 0. I am still getting 42 rather than 42.5. How can I make it up to 2 decimal places?

Comment: use **parseFloat** instead, in such a case and use **toFixed(2)** to force that value to have 2 decimals. In a nushell, do this: `document.getElementById('total-price').setAttribute("value", (parseFloat(document.getElementById("total-price").value) + 42).toFixed(2));` and apply the same logic to the -42. new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s95hvsp5/2/ (adding 42.3 as an example)